# I want to upgrade from 10.04 but I don't know how since update hangs

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, update-manager

I would like to upgrade my current LTS version of Ubuntu to a new version.

Current version:

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
- Release:        10.04
- Codename:       lucid

Somehow, the update manager hangs. So I can't start the upgrade that way.

I've tried several suggested options using the command line, but every time I get the message (in Dutch) that the original situation is recovered, then an abort message and then:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
=== Command detached from window (Mon Oct 12 18:17:42 2015) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Oct 12 18:17:42 2015) ===
```

I mainly use the computer as a fileserver, mailserver, webserver, to run Dovecot, Fetchmail (among other things).

What is the best approach? How can accomplish this without any hassle?

Comment: Questions about Ubuntu 10.04 are not supported on this site, as only questions about currently supported versions of Ubuntu are supported. You should really upgrade at least to the latest LTS version (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it is possible to upgrade an Ubuntu LTS version to the next version (12.04 to 14.04),
I strongly recommend the clean installation of a current supported system such as 14.04.
The support of Ubuntu 10.04 ended in April this year and ... this system is five years old !
Most of the included software, like kernels, frameworks and applications are outdated.
The experience of users attempting an upgrade of such an old system is not very good.

Comment: That's an answer I can use. Now there's one more thing: I have mail and files that I want to keep. What's the best way to keep it? Can I do an install and keep my user space ? (both my mail and files are kept under my home directory. Files under samba.) The problem also is that I set up all the stuff five years ago and really can't remember how to do that again, that's why I would like to upgrade.

Comment: @RJJB68 : There are two possibilities - 1. Copy the files you want to keep to another drive or partition or 2. Make a backup of files and folders you want to keep with a tool like deja-dup and restore them after having finished the installation of the new system. :)

Comment: Always make a backup - the installer should offer to upgrade the existing installation, which will keep the `/home` partition which should normally have all your data on.